# Printing output from my linq query in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using asp.net core entity framework.  I am trying to print out the results of my query into my html.  Here is my code.

This is my `.cs` file

```
ViewBag.User_Has_Products = (from user_products in _context.Users_Has_Products
                             join user in _context.Users on user_products.users_id equals user.id 
                             join product in _context.Products on user_products.products_id equals product.id 
                             select new { name =  user.name, product = product.name, 
                                          quantity = user_products.quanitity, date = user_products.created_at});

foreach(var item in ViewBag.User_Has_Products)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine($"{item.name}"); //this output is correct
}
```

Here is my `.cshtml` page

```
@{
    if(ViewBag.User_Has_Products != null)
    {
        foreach(var item in ViewBag.User_Has_Products)
        {
            <p>@$"{item.name}"</p> //trying to print it out here
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried `<p>@item.name</p>` but got an object does not contain a definition for name error.

Comment: As Tha'er mentioned in his answer, creating a model or class; Do your queries in a DAL section of your project, that does its calls to the database (or where ever) and store the data in a container. Example a User class with a Product List or Category.

Comment: You can try creating a ViewModel class with all the properties needed for your view. Then project your select as a list of the ViewModel objects instead of anonymous object list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the string quotes in your `.cshtml` file, just use it as is, see the following example:

```
@{
    if(ViewBag.User_Has_Products != null)
    {
        foreach(var item in ViewBag.User_Has_Products)
        {
            <p>@item.name</p>
        }
    }
}
```

But the better recommendation is to build a `model` and send it to your `view`, like this:

```
public class UserProductsViewmodel() {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Product { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
     public string Date { get; set;}
}
```

and use it in your `.cs` file like this:

```
ViewBag.User_Has_Products = (from user_products in _context.Users_Has_Products
                             join user in _context.Users on user_products.users_id equals user.id 
                             join product in _context.Products on user_products.products_id equals product.id 
                             select new UserProductsViewmodel() { 
                                  Name =  user.name, Product = product.name, 
                                  Quantity = user_products.quanitity, Date = user_products.created_at
                              });
```

And in your `.cshtml` like this:

```
@{
    if(ViewBag.User_Has_Products != null)
    {
        foreach(UserProductsViewmodel item in ViewBag.User_Has_Products)
        {
            <p>@item.Name</p>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but am getting an object does not contain a definition for name error

Comment: Try to create a model that contains all your properties (name, product, quantity ...etc) instead of using `anonymous` objects, that will help fixing the latter error.

Comment: Can you give me an example?  I am not really sure what you are about.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using ViewBag instead of using Model for the view? Using Model bound views would be more in control and provide you compile time feedback if anything is not correct.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I am new to asp.net core and the only examples I have seen are Viewbag.  Can you explain a little but about Model Bound Views?

Answer (score 0):

Check this article on [Dependency injection into views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection) which will a better way than using ViewBag.

Controller action snippet

```
public IActionResult GetProducts()
{

    var products = (from user_products in _context.Users_Has_Products
                         join user in _context.Users on user_products.users_id equals user.id 
                         join product in _context.Products on user_products.products_id equals product.id 
                         select new UserProductsViewmodel() { 
                              Name =  user.name, Product = product.name, 
                              Quantity = user_products.quanitity, Date = user_products.created_at
                          });
    return View(products);
}
```

View snippet(.cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<namespace.ProductModel>
...

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.Bar</p>
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ProductModel() {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Product { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
     public string Date { get; set;}
}
```